# Insert space after every punctuation sign in a String Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I have this function that checks if a character is one of these punctuation signs.

```
checkpunctuation:: Char -> Bool
checkpunctuationc = c `elem` ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']
```

I have to write another function that after every punctuation sign it adds a space

```
format :: String -> String
```

I know how to add space after a given number of characthers but don't know how to add after specific characters.

Comment: `format` is `concatMap f` for some `f`.

Comment: @Gurkenglas: thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simple recursive option:

```
format :: String -> String
format [] = []
format (x:xs) | checkpuntuationc x = x : ' ' : format xs
              | otherwise          = x : format xs
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but

```
format :: String -> String
format s = concat [if (checkpunctuation c) then (c:" ") else [c] | c <- s]
```

will work (thanks, @Shou Ya!).

---

**Edit based on comment**

To count the total length of post-formatted punctuation characters, you can use

```
sumLength :: [String] -> Int 
sumLength strings = 2 * (sum $ fmap length (fmap (filter checkpunctuation) strings))
```

as the it is twice the sum of the number of punctuation characters.

Comment: @Amy Tavory: Thanks

Comment: Instead of `intercalate ""` you can just use `concat`.

Comment: @AmyTavory: If before I add space I must calculate the sum length of the crings that have punctuation signs?  only with function, do you have any idea about how to do it?

Comment: @Madalina Not sure what you mean by "strings that have punctuation signs". You have one string, and some characters *are* punctuations, no? Do you want to count how many characters are punctuation characters?

Comment: @AmyTavory: instead of String I have a list of stringssomething like  sumLength :: [String] -> Int

Comment: @Madalina Edited the answer based on what I understood you're asking.

Comment: @AmyTavory: sumLength ["ana:","sdfghj","::"] must return 6, now it return 12(all characters) + 3 (only punctuatin signs)= 15

Comment: @Madalina OK, so you meant something a bit different. See updated answer.

Comment: @AmyTavory: Thank you, can you explain me a little what $ does? I cannot understand :) and i really want to be able to resolve this problems by myself

Comment: @Madalina You can think of it as a syntactic sugar for writing `f $ g x y` instead of `f (g x y)` (heuristically, it means something like apply it to the result of whatever comes to the right of `$`).

Comment: @AmyTavory: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `foldr` with a `helper` function:

```
helper :: Char -> String -> String
helper x xs | checkpunctuation x = x : ' ' : xs
            | otherwise = x : xs
```

The helper checks if the first character is a punctuation. If so it inserts a space, otherwise it does not.

and then define `format` as:

```
format :: String -> String
format = foldr helper []
```

A sample call:

```
*Main> format "Hello? Goodbye! You say goodbye!! (and I say Hello)"
"Hello?  Goodbye!  You say goodbye! !  ( and I say Hello) "
```

This function works also on "*infinite* strings":

```
*Main> take 50 $ format $ cycle "Hello?Goodbye!"
"Hello? Goodbye! Hello? Goodbye! Hello? Goodbye! He"
```

So although we feed it a string that keeps `cycle`-ing, and thus never ends, we can derive the first 50 characters of the result.